# Trying to kill tasks that have been started in a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I am trying to start a butch of programs at once but then I want to to be able to kill all those programs at a later time. So I have created two bat files one to start the programs in the file and one to stop them.

This is the bat file that should stop them.

```
for /r "." %%a in (*.exe) do taskkill /IM %%~nxI  
pause
```

It gives me an error that file was not found here is the error that it gave me. > ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'D:\FileName'

Here is the code that starts them:

```
for /r "." %%a in (*.exe) do start "" "%%~fa"
pause
```

Comment: The for variable `%%a` is the fully qualified path to the executable.  `TASKKILL` is just expecting the executable name and you are missing the `/IM` option for the `TASKKILL` command.

Comment: So how would I get the executable name I have been trying to use set x=%%a
    set x=echo !x:%cd%=!  but can not get it to work?

Comment: So you somehow knew what `~f` was doing in a `FOR` command but didn't read all the modifiers you can use in the HELP file for the `FOR` command?  Open up a command prompt and type: `FOR /?`.  Read the last section.

Comment: Also, with the `FOR` command you are using to `START` the executables, you do not need the `~f` modifier.  The `FOR` variable `%%a` is already the fully qualified path because you are using the `/R` option.

Comment: The start program works I am trying to get the taskkill to work.  I updated the stop code

Comment: `%%I` is not your `FOR` variable. `%%a` is.

Comment: okay sorry I am new to batch files

Comment: Got it thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To kill all the tasks in the file:

```
for /r "." %%a in (*.exe) do taskkill /IM "%%~nxa" 

pause
```